# Is there any way to add Edit Text Dynamically depending on the webservice?

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout

I have a webservice and depending on that webservice I get data such as name, email etc . And the data changes depending on the webservice. i.e Some webservice might have only two fields ,some might have 3 fields . So my question is how Can I add the EditText field dynamically depending on the webservice?

Comment: What if I say You can do it!!

Comment: My reply would be... HOW?

Comment: Are you asking how to create new EditText in code or how to edit existing ones?

Comment: Add the number of `EditText` fields you need dynamically using [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would approach this is to have a layout with the maximum number of fields. So if there were 3 you would simply look at what the Web Service returns and change the visibility of the fields depending on what you needed.

You would do this using the [setVisibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) method of the `View` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class that store a `field label` and `EditText` responsible for capture value for this field, you also need a `ids xml` file to store `id` of that `editText` with the name of the field to letter retrieve captured values, then, when you parse all your service response and you created all those object, you can iterate over there and call the `EditText` creator method, look like this.

```
class EditTextResponse extends EditText{

private String label;
private EditText edit;

public EditTextResponse(Context context,String label) {
    super(context); 
    this.label  =label; 
     init();
}

private void init(){        
    this.setId( getReflectedId() );
}

private int getReflectedId(){
    Class<?> ids = R.id.class;
    try{
        Field field = ids.getField( label );
        return field.getInt(null);
    }catch( Exception ex ){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return android.R.id.text1;
}
```

}

Your `ids xml` look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <item name="email" type="id"/>
  <item name="name" type="id"/>
  <item name="other" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

and then in you activity. you can iterate over those `FieldResponse` objects and go to attaching to view.